# Why am I getting an Invalid dataSetArn message when trying to build an AWS Quicksight project using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to deploy an AWS Quicksight project using Terraform.

Here is my Terraform config:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sample_data" {
  bucket = "testing-quicksight-dataset"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "csv" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sample_data.bucket
    key = "business-operations-survey-2022-business-finance.csv"
    source = data.local_file.csv.filename
}

resource "aws_quicksight_data_source" "datasource" {
  data_source_id = "testdata"
  name           = "testdata"

  parameters {
    s3 {
      manifest_file_location {
        bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sample_data.id
        key    = "manifest.json"
      }
    }
  }

  type = "S3"
}

resource "aws_quicksight_data_set" "example" {
  data_set_id = aws_quicksight_data_source.datasource.id
  name        = "testdata"
  import_mode = "SPICE"

  physical_table_map {
    physical_table_map_id = "testdata"
    s3_source {
      data_source_arn = "${aws_quicksight_data_source.datasource.arn}"
      input_columns {
        name = "description"
        type = "STRING"
      }
      upload_settings {
        format    = "CSV"
        delimiter = ","
      }
    }
  }

  depends_on = [aws_quicksight_data_source.datasource]
}

resource "aws_quicksight_template" "bar_chart" {
  template_id         = "bar-chart"
  name                = "bar-chart"
  version_description = "desc"
  definition {
    data_set_configuration {
      data_set_schema {
        column_schema_list {
          name      = "industry"
          data_type = "STRING"
        }
        column_schema_list {
          name      = "value"
          data_type = "INTEGER"
        }
      }
      placeholder = "1"
    }
    sheets {
      title    = "Industry - Value"
      sheet_id = "Barchart"
      visuals {
        bar_chart_visual {
          visual_id = "BarChart"
          chart_configuration {
            field_wells {
              bar_chart_aggregated_field_wells {
                category {
                  categorical_dimension_field {
                    field_id = "1"
                    column {
                      column_name         = "industry"
                      data_set_identifier = "1"
                    }
                  }
                }
                values {
                  numerical_measure_field {
                    field_id = "2"
                    column {
                      column_name         = "value"
                      data_set_identifier = "1"
                    }
                    aggregation_function {
                      simple_numerical_aggregation = "SUM"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to Terraform, the above is a valid configuration. I expect it to create an S3 bucket and upload a CSV, then use the CSV as a data source for Quicksight. I also expect a template to be created based on the template definition. I have not yet started to create an analysis/dashboard.

The error I get when running `terraform apply` is this:

```
aws_quicksight_data_set.example: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating QuickSight Data Set: InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid dataSetArn
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "8fe0ad1d-ea16-44e0-8ad5-eb71d308044d"
│   },
│   Message_: "Invalid dataSetArn"
│ }
│ 
│   with aws_quicksight_data_set.example,
│   on aws_quicksight.tf line 24, in resource "aws_quicksight_data_set" "example":
│   24: resource "aws_quicksight_data_set" "example" {
│
```

So far, I have tried using the equivalent `awscc_quicksight...` providers and have received the same error. I have also tried to define the dataset arn as both `"${aws_quicksight_data_source.datasource.arn}"` and `aws_quicksight_data_source.datasource.arn` - same error.

Is this an error on the AWS side? Is there a way to work around the invalid dataset arn?